# is this considered a rank 2 tensor or a rank 3 tenso

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
tensor1 = tf.ones([1,2,3]) 
print(tensor1)
>>>tf.Tensor(
[[[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]], shape=(1, 2, 3), dtype=float32)
```

I have started studying tensorflow recently, and I've bumped into this(code above) in a tutorial.
I believe that in tf.ones[1,2,3]
-the 3 at the end represents the number of elements inside each dimension
-the 2 represents the number of dimensions inside
However, I am confused with what the 1 at the start is meant to represent, so can someone clarify that please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That one refers to that dimension being of length 1. Note the extra [] around your tensor.

Thus the shapes work based on the nested length of the tensor values

ie: Shape (2, 3, 4) of zeros would be

```
[ #A tensor
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0 ,0]], #note the two subdivisions, 
 [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0 ,0]]  #then 3, then 4 zeros
]
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm sorry if this is another really simple question, but what does the length of the tensor mean exactly?

Comment: basically each nested part of the tensor has its own length. referencing by len(tensor[some index]) will give you different lengths based on the level of nesting. ie len(tensor[some index]) != len(tensor[some index][other index]). SO when asking about the size, there is a length for each dimension of the tensor which defines the shape. Consider a nth dimensional array and the length of each side is the given value of the shape. Not unlike a rectangle or cube.

Comment: So does it basically mean that 
[1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1.]
is inside a list, which is inside another list?
Thank you!

Comment: dim 1: length 1 [], dim 2: Length 2 [[], []], dim 3: Length 3 [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]